# Grails: Always getting the first element of list in g:each

Tags: image, grails, gsp

Iterating list(pedaTechList) in GSP page using g:each tag and building image with different URLS. The problem is I am always getting first element of pedaTechList for "${ped.id}" while building the URL for assign below. The code snippet is below. Please help to resolve this.

```
<g:each in="${pedaTechList}" var="ped" >
<div class="imgblock">
    <img style="height: 130px;"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'unfav-unchecked.png')}" alt="Criteria" usemap="#p_icons" />
    <div class="smallblackarea">
            <map name="p_icons">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,18,18" href="${createLink(controller: 'pedagogy', action: 'reloadPedagogyTab', id: imod?.id, params: [objectiveId: params.objectiveId, fav:'true', assign:'false'])}" title="Favorite" alt="Favorite" />
            **<area shape="rect" coords="90,0,126,24" href="${createLink(controller: 'pedagogy', action: 'reloadPedagogyTab', id: imod?.id, params: [objectiveId: params.objectiveId, pedtecID: "${ped.id}", fav:'false', assign:'true'])}" title="Assign" alt="Assign" />**
            <area shape="rect" coords="90,90,200,200" href="http://www.google.com/" title="Clone" alt="Clone" />            
            </map>
    ${ped.pedagogyTitle}
    </div>              
</div> 
</g:each>
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape double quotes `\"${ped.id}\"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation:
http://blog.freeside.co/post/46587122020/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope

Gstrings contain closures which get evaluated later in this case. In your example you can replace 
    pedtecID: "${ped.id}" 
with 
    pedtecID: ped.id
or 
   pedtecID: "${ped.id}" as String